# How could I use ng-options in a Select on this object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have an object called groupList that looks like this:

```
{
  "12777e85-c03a-97ba-42ce-3242b6bd4109": {
    "id": "12777e85-c03a-97ba-42ce-3242b6bd4109",
    "name": "uber name for group"
  },
  "57415d36-e935-cc6a-11b4-0b95bce5cb95": {
    "id": "57415d36-e935-cc6a-11b4-0b95bce5cb95",
    "name": "a group name"
  },
  "65c9cf1d-0876-1faf-7986-e44bbba8d0fe": {
    "id": "65c9cf1d-0876-1faf-7986-e44bbba8d0fe",
    "name": "users"
  },
  "d3525828-0b53-a7eb-6c17-ea142a54687e": {
    "id": "d3525828-0b53-a7eb-6c17-ea142a54687e",
    "name": "admin"
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to use that in a select box. I can ng-repeat through the data with no problem simply by doing `ng-repeat="group in groupList` but that doesn't work as well for ng-option. I'm getting precariously close with: `ng-options="name for (id, name) in groupList"` where groupList is the object that I'm working against. I'm just not quite there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your best bet is to just javascript to strip and manipulate that object into a much easier to use one (to be honest).

Comment: Your object is not really nice ... It would be easier if you remove the key.
Look this codePen and tell me if you agree with that (if yes i will publish and explain it as answer) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbGJxM

Comment: The best is modify rest api - you obviously return Map. Return Map#values instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5zc576az/9/) what you are after?

```
<select ng-options="key as value.name for (key, value) in groupList" ng-model="selected"/>
```